# How to fix scope issue between my jquery+flash plugin and require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I got a [pull request](https://github.com/patricklodder/jquery-zclip/pull/2) on GitHub today for a [small jquery plugin](https://github.com/patricklodder/jquery-zclip) proposing a little hack in it's master branch because the Flash element of the plugin doesn't work with [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) closures. It comes down to Flash needing a global variable, so the scope changes after loading through require.js and the variable is no longer seen.

The proposed fix in the pull request is to omit declaration, so basically:

```
foo = { "bar": 1 };
```

instead of:

```
var foo = { "bar": 1 };
```

but that prohibits jslint passing forever, so I don't really want to do that.

Should i fix this in my main script with something like:

```
var foo = { "bar": 1 };
if ( typeof(window) === 'object' ) { window['foo'] = foo; }
```

or should I encourage this to be fixed in the implementation rather than in my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the third party need direct control over the variable? You can add the line `window.foo = foo` at the end.

However, it would be safer be to have a `getFoo()` method that returns the value, that way you keep control over the variable.

Comment: That's a very valid point, I will go with this unless someone else has a better idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you require a global variable for Flash, then I suggest **creating a proper namespace for your application** so the Flash can access it through a single point of entry.

```
// create your objects for your app
var foo = {
    bar: 1
};

// add your object to the global namespace  eg. 'myApp'
window.myApp = foo;
```

This article might help: http://www.2ality.com/2011/04/modules-and-namespaces-in-javascript.html

Comment: The entire script is namespaced already, so I guess that's covered as long as people don't intend to run multiple versions of my script. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could provide an initialization parameter allowing the consumer of your library to choose where to stick it to.

```
require(['theflashlibrary'], function(theFlashLibrary){

    theFlashLibrary.init({ globalProperty: 'foo' }); //Otherwise this could default to something else...
});
```

I don't have a good way of doing this, but, I feel that it would be nice to at least provide a way for the user to choose where will your library be referenced.

Comment: Although that would be ideal, the problem with this is that the compiled flash object needs a predefined access point in global scope, and since it's compiled into an swf, I need to set it.